# How do I upload a file to google drive api using axios? I always get a 400 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to google drive, I have used the refresh_token to get new access_token for every request. How do I set up the request using axios

I have setup according to the details in the link https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('mimeType', this.state.title);
data.append('name', `sermon-${Date.now()}.mp3`);
data.append('originalFilename', this.state.file.name);
data.append('parents[]', SERMON_FOLDER);
data.append('sermon', this.state.file);

Axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable`, data, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Content-Length': this.state.file.size,
                Authorization: `Bearer ${response.data.token}`
              },
              onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                const percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
                this.setState({ progress: percentCompleted });
              }
            })
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                this.setState({ isLoading: false });
                ToastAndroid.show('Upload Successful, Your Sermon has been uploaded', 2500);
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Admin');
              }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({ isLoading: false });
                ToastAndroid.show('Connection Error', 3000)
              });
```

I expect to get a response but the actual response is a 400 bad request from server.

Comment: you haven't correctly implemented Resumable Upload. You need to carefully read https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Comment: @chitgoks I ended up using cloudinary as I was pressed for time. You?

Comment: @AndrewOgaga check out react-google-picker. it works.

Answer (score 0):

As per google-api requirements you need to send your metadata in file format

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append(
  "metadata",
  new Blob([JSON.stringify({ name: file.name, mimeType: "audio/*", parents: [ROOT_FOLDER_ID] })], {
    type: "application/json",
  }),
);
formData.append("file", file);
```